# php 71 does not create php7.0-fpm.sock

Tags: php, nginx

I am trying to set up a Wordpress Server using RedHat 7.3, Nginx 1.10 and PHP71.

This is the steps of how I installed the PHP71:

wget http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

rpm -Uvh remi-release-7.rpm
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php71
yum install php71

To see that it was installed:
rpm -q php71 and it returned php71-1.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64
This shows it was installed.

Also running php71 -v gives me the following so I am confident it is installed:
PHP 7.1.4 (cli) (built: Apr 11 2017 18:26:18) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

So what I am trying to do is use Unix Socket rather than IP:

In the www.conf files I have set user and group both to Nginx
I change the listen value to the following:
    /var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock
I match that up with what is in the default.conf file inside of /etc/nginx.

My problem is that it looks like PHP71 never created this file php7.0-fpm.sock.

I did get this to work with PHP56 so am wondering if I need to install some PHP71 module.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check the obvious? php7.0-fpm.sock stands for PHP 7.0, so if you're installing PHP 7.1 ... look for php7.1-fpm.sock?

Comment: Tried that earlier and did not work - Thank you

Answer (score 2):

php does not create any sockets by itself.

Looks like you did not install php-fpm package.

job of php-fpm deamon is to create *-fpm.sock

Find how to install and configure php-fpm on your system

Comment: Yes I installed php71-php-fpm - it works when the listen is set to:127.0.0.1:9000.  The problem is with listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock as I want to use UNIX socket and not IP.  thank you.

Comment: interesting. could you post your fpm config?

Comment: so you have listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock in you fpm config and you have </br>  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock; in you nginx config?

Comment: So sorry for the late reply - I managed to resolve this by uninstalling / reverting in VM and reinstalled everything.  I managed to get it to work.  Thank you everyone for your help